# Replacing all negative values in all columns by zero in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have below df

```
date              T1   T2  T3  T4
1-1-2010 00:10    20   -5  4   3
1-1-2010 00:20    85  -78  34  21
1-1-2010 00:30    -45  22  31  75 
1-1-2010 00:40    -6   5   7  -28
```

I would like to replace negative value into zero from 1st(from T1 columns) columns onwards.

i tried below code:

```
df.iloc[:,1:].mask(df, 0)
```

but its also showing '0' values of date columns.

final output should be:

```
date              T1   T2  T3  T4
1-1-2010 00:10    20   0   4   3
1-1-2010 00:20    85   0   34  21
1-1-2010 00:30    0    22  31  75 
1-1-2010 00:40    0    5   7    0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! can you update the `df` like a list of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].clip(0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             date  T1  T2  T3  T4
0  1-1-2010 00:10  20   0   4   3
1  1-1-2010 00:20  85   0  34  21
2  1-1-2010 00:30   0  22  31  75
3  1-1-2010 00:40   0   5   7   0
```

Not only `clip` is faster than `mask` in your sample, but also in the larger dataset:

```
# Your sample -> 3x faster
%timeit df.iloc[:, 1:].clip(0)
# 1.74 ms ± 115 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.iloc[:,1:].mask(df.iloc[:,1:] < 0, 0)
# 5.25 ms ± 573 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
# Large Sample -> 1,000,000 elements --> about 30x
large_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randint(-5, 5, (1000, 1000)))

%timeit large_df.clip(0)
# 17.2 ms ± 2.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit large_df.mask(large_df< 0, 0)
# 498 ms ± 47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: a smart way to use `clip` !

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `df` with `df.iloc[:,1:] < 0`

```py
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].mask(df.iloc[:,1:] < 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df1.iloc[:,1:]
df = df.mask(df<0 , 0)
```

Hope this will Helps.!:)

Comment: it removes `date` column from `df`